# Establishing a dataframe to forecast univariate data

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm trying to figure out the R code to forecast a univariate dataset. I have data for approximately 60 days and want a forecast with the values for the predicted mean, as well as upper & lower bounds for at least the next 30 days. I've been trying to using the following code, but I've been seemingly unsuccessful.

```
fit <- auto.arima(tsData)
plot(forecast(fit, h=30))
summary(fit)
```

If someone could assist me with the proper code for the dataframe to forecast and extract these values, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Leah, can you please provide a sample of your data? It’s impossible to help you otherwise. :-)

Comment: Your code looks correct. The problem must be related to the class of your tsData

Comment: In what way is `auto.arima` unsuccessful? Do you get an error message?

Comment: The auto.arima is unsuccessful because it is giving me a flat line for the forecast, so I don't think it is taking in the data properly. That's why I was thinking I may need to change the function/add parameters to get R to provide me what I'm looking for.

Comment: I defined the name of my dataset as tsData, so that may be part of the problem.

Comment: @Edo here is some of the data: 
3370697
2991236
4332207
5208166
4338202
3906104
2499007
5407081
4936893
2489895
3477738
4849286
3645099
2286487
4829361
2317651
2312448
2947272
2820730
3349846
4828345
4320237
5636653
2357571
4344268
3147261
2289202
4016317
3905877
5042027
4951175
4425748
5595234
4297312
4731678
2594187
4297152
3148697
3209767
4112872
4660192
2441161
3351706
4102640
4034730
2572022
4396384
2833348
4401217
4996111
4762427
2367626
4914486
5035678
3050084
5718706
4778152

Comment: For the auto.arima to function correctly you need to provide it with a ts object. Have you specified the frequency on your ts? You have daily data, thus your frequency should be 7. tsData <- ts(tsData, frequency = 7)

Comment: @edo Ah that makes sense! I included the line of code for the frequency and it is working properly now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @edo I'm sorry, one more question: now that I have the forecast how do I extract the values and bounds?

Comment: I'll add below a full working example, okay? feel free to change the parameters based on your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the comments to your post, we defined that your problem was related to the fact that you **did not specify a frequency** into your ts object.

The following code answers to the last question you asked in one of your comments. I would suggest you to update your question so that other people may find this answer more useful.

**The code below helps you define a dataframe composed of upper bounds, lower bounds and forecast from a `forecast` object**.

```
library(forecast)

# the chunk of data you left in the comments
tsData <- c(3370697,2991236,4332207,5208166,
            4338202,3906104,2499007,5407081,
            4936893,2489895,3477738,4849286,
            3645099,2286487,4829361,2317651,
            2312448,2947272,2820730,3349846,
            4828345,4320237,5636653,2357571,
            4344268,3147261,2289202,4016317,
            3905877,5042027,4951175,4425748,
            5595234,4297312,4731678,2594187,
            4297152,3148697,3209767,4112872,
            4660192,2441161,3351706,4102640,
            4034730,2572022,4396384,2833348,
            4401217,4996111,4762427,2367626,
            4914486,5035678,3050084,5718706,4778152)

# set up frequency
tsData <- ts(tsData, frequency = 7)

# your code!
fit <- auto.arima(tsData)
fcst <- forecast(fit, h = 30)
plot(fcst)

# get a data.frame with your forecast, lower and upper bounds 
res <- ts.union(lower = fcst$lower, forecast = fcst$mean, upper = fcst$upper)
res <- as.data.frame(res)
res
```

to help you understand what I'm doing here: the object called `fcst` is an object of class `forecast`. A `forecast` is basically a list and it is composed by many items. You can see the names of all the items by typing:

```
names(fcst)
```

and you can see them all if you type:

```
tmp <- fcst
class(tmp) <- "list"
tmp
```

Call any object you need with the operator `$` exactly as you would do with any list.

```
# for example
fcst$mean
fcst$upper
fcst$lower
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks a bunch! I really appreciate it. I was finding bits and pieces of the solution online, but was having a hard time tying it all together. So, this helps a lot! I will be sure to modify the question, so that it is more helpful